# Getting url of the current page

Tags: php, html

I am trying to get the website url of the current page on which the person is. I would use it in the social share buttons that I am creating. The websites are all Wordpress websites. I got the following url for getting the current url,

```
<?php if (is_home()) { echo site_url(); } else {  echo the_permalink(); } ?>
```

The script does not execute and when I click the button, the url does not generate but the php  script is displayed in the browser as it is.

Please help out. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would use

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>
```

This gives you the url of the current page. For example `index.php` or something similar

Comment: Thanks. The weird thing is that the `php` script did not even executed.

Comment: Perhaps this is to do with your script location? Is it on a template file?

Comment: Have a look at it. Its the plugin on the left side of the [website](http://www.apptec.net/why-should-i-buy-iphone4s-part1-5/).

Comment: Here is the link generated after clicking the 4th button which is the script you told. 
`https://plusone.google.com/_/+1/confirm?hl=en-US&url=%3C?php%20echo%20$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];%20?%3E`

Comment: Its being encoded for some reason (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) can you jsfiddle a bit more of your code where you are trying to use it?

Comment: Using it in a wordpress plugin to create similar share buttons as displayed on stackoverflow

Comment: Your code looks fine, it must be something related to wordpress

Comment: An interesting thing that I just noticed is that if the image contains a `php` script, it would not show the target link when you hover around it, else it does. **Hover over the share buttons on top** and hover over the one my page. The one on my page **starts to display the php code** as you hover around.

Answer (score 1):

Using Javascript:

```
var currentURL = document.URL;
alert(currentURL);
```

Using PHP:

```
<?php
function curPageURL() {
 $pageURL = 'http';
 if ($_SERVER["HTTPS"] == "on") {$pageURL .= "s";}
 $pageURL .= "://";
 if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != "80") {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].":".$_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 } else {
  $pageURL .= $_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
 }
 return $pageURL;
}
?>
```

If you want file name
Use PHP Magic Constants such as `__FILE__`